# GridFS Binary to URL

Tags: javascript, mongodb, url, binary, gridfs

Is there a way to convert GridFS binary to a URL that can be used on a src?

Let me explain:

When an image is stored on mongoDB by GridFS it creates to files(fs.files & fs.chunks).
In fs.chunks the data is stored like so:

```
_id:ObjectID('')
files_id:ObjectID('')
n:0
data:Binary('/9j/4S...',0)
```

Exist any way to convert that binary which is an image(a jpg to be precise) into a URL valid for a HTML img tag?

Some kind of URL.createObjectURL()

By the way, I tried to pass the binary file into URL.createObjectURL() and the displayed error is the following:

```
TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally find a helpful answer to my question on this other question:

[Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Here, the GridFS binary which is a base64 binary is converted in to a Blob object. Then the Blob object can be easily passed through the "URL.createObjectURL()"

The function to convert the base64 to blob is provided in the answer.

I hope this is helpfull for someone else.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you want